# Blazor Routing and Static File (PDF) Conflict

Tags: pdf, asp.net-core, routes, blazor

Creating a Blazor server-side application that is a Wiki, in the style of Wiki.js (but with .net, of course)

Since the users create the pages, this is mostly a SPA with `index.razor` matching the following:

```
@page "/"
@page "/{PageLink}"
@page "/{Folder}/{PageLink}"
```

Unfortunately, since I'm trying to migrate an existing `Wiki.js` wiki, I'm trying to keep their file structure, where `uploads` lives inside the main repo folder. Thus, `index.razor` catches. `.../uploads/file.pdf` and tries to render it as a wiki page (Folder = `uploads`, PageLink = `file.pdf`).

I was able to add this to `Startup.cs` which helps:

```
app.Map("/uploads", fileApp =>
        {
            fileApp.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"WikiPages", @"uploads")),
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
            });
        });
```

Putting that before `app.UseEndpoints` means that, typing or pasting the path `http://localhost/uploads/file.pdf` now works, and shows my pdf. However, on a wiki page, clicking the link `<a href="uploads/file.pdf">File</a>` does not work, and still triggers the `index.razor` route. Shift-click, Ctrl-click, right-click and "Open in new Tab" all *work*, but a basic click does not.

I know that in the future, Blazor may have more advanced routing support, which would allow me to "exclude" the folder `uploads` from `index.razor`. In the meantime, how would I fix these links to show my pdf?

(full code is at [Bliki](https://github.com/TimPurdum/Bliki))

Comment: As a workaround, I have been able to set my markdown renderer to add `target="_blank"` to each file link, but since this is more avoiding the problem than fixing it, I'm not going to set it as the answer.